# bounds - uniform convergence

Tags: calculus

For a fixed r and large n, how was the following bound derived:

${n^2 - r^2}  \geq \frac{n^2}{2}$

I get the following which is not useful, as I need a lower bound:
${n^2 - r^2}  \leq n^2$

I need to bound the following that does not depend on z, and we are given $|z| \leq r$
$|| \frac{nz}{n^2 + z^2} || =  \frac{n|z|}{|n^2 + z^2|} \leq \frac{n|z|}{n^2 - |z|^2} \leq \frac{nr}{n^2 - r^2}  \leq \frac{nr}{n^2 - r^2}  $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $n> \sqrt {2r^2}.$ Then $n^2 > 2r^2,$ i.e. $n^2/2 > r^2.$  Thus

$$n^2 - r^2 > n^2 - n^2/2 = n^2/2.$$

Comment: Actually $ \frac{nr}{n^2 - r^2} \to 0 $ as $n \to \infty $ as r is fixed.